# how to change google maps marker icon image dynamically in a set interval function in java script?

Tags: javascript, api, google-maps

In a set interval function, I am changing value of a variable and depending on the value of that variable I want to change image of icon without reloading complete page?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming `marker`  is your marker object  you can change marker icon without reload page simply using  setIcon

```
marker.setIcon( 'http://your_domain.com/your-custom-icon.png');
```

assuming that you have an array of marker  with a numeric index eg : my_markers  and you have store the marker icon in proper var,  you can change the single  marker with

```
 var my_icon=  'http://your_domain.com/your-custom-icon.png';

    for (i=0; i<my_markers.length; i++){
          markers[i].setIcon(my_icon);
    }
```